# I want to get array of rows affected by the $sql.But following code is not working.It gives only first record?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, phpmyadmin, oracle9i

```
oci_execute($sql);  
for($x = 1; $x <= oci_fetch_Array($sql); $x++)  
{
    $rows[]= oci_fetch_assoc($sql);
}
return $rows;
```

Comment: Why not look in the manual which has examples? http://php.net/manual/de/function.oci-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using oci_execute without oci_parse I guess?

For example,

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

See the [examples.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php)